# How to check if there exist a path running through all nodes in an adjacency list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, hashmap, adjacency-list

I recently created an unweighted bidirectional graph by using an adjacency list from a HashMap in Java. I have randomly created connections between nodes and now I am unsure of how to check if there's a single path that passes through every node once and exactly once.

What is the best way / algorithm to check if a path exists between all nodes?

```
//Sample
A -> B
B -> A -> C -> D
C -> B -> E
D -> B
E -> C -> G
F -> G
G -> E -> F
```

Comment: Do you mean whether there are paths between all pairs of nodes in the graph, or whether there’s a single path with no repeating nodes that goes through all nodes in the graph?

Comment: Yes, to check for a single path with no repeating nodes that goes through all nodes in the path

Answer (score 2):

The sort of path you’re asking for is called a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) and unfortunately there are no known algorithms for this problem that run efficiently on all inputs (the problem is **NP**-complete). You could solve this problem by brute force (list all possible paths and see if any of them go through all the nodes once and exactly once). There’s also a famous O(n<sup>2</sup>2<sup>n</sup>)-time dynamic programming algorithm for this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DFS](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/) or [BFS](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/) algorithm to traverse the graph and check if each of the nodes is visited at least once.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about Hamiltonian paths, not general graph connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know whether the graph is connected or not then you can do the following:

1. Use BFS/DFS to map the graph starting from any of the nodes. Whenever you encounter a new node (including the first one) increase a counter by 1. This will give you the number of connected nodes to your starting node.
2. Compare that counter with the size of the map (number of keys). If the number of keys is greater than the number of nodes traversed then the graph is disconnected, if the number is equal then it is connected.

It's not really clear what your data structure is because you're talking about a `HashMap`, but showing something else. Generally, BFS/DFS run in *O(|V| + |E|)* (where *|V|* is the number of vertices and *|E|* is the number of edges), and `size` is *O(1)* for a `HashMap`.

If you want to know which nodes are not connected to your starting one, then

- Store or mark all the nodes you traverse. This will give you all the nodes connected to the node from which you initiated the traversing.
- Iterate over all the nodes and find those which are not contained in your previous step.

`contains` is also *O(1)* for a `HashMap`, though you would have to run it *|V|-1* times.

There's a similar (more theory oriented) question on Computer Science: [How to check whether a graph is connected in polynomial time?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/how-to-check-whether-a-graph-is-connected-in-polynomial-time)

Comment: The data structure is using a HashMap to keep track of all the nodes, and an ArrayList of adjacent nodes for each value in the HashMap

Comment: @ChristopherTan Then why not tell this crucial information in the question? Show your data structure explicitly.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about Hamiltonian paths, not general graph connectivity.

Comment: @user1803551 I agree with you - I had to ask for a clarification.